# How to view ClassifierFunction's preprocessed data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

`Classify` apparently preprocesses your input data, for example (same example from `Classify` reference page, but using `NeuralNetwork` as the method):

```
Othello = Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2267/pg2267.txt"];
Hamlet = Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2265/pg2265.txt"];
Macbeth = Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2264/pg2264.txt"];
TheImportanceOfBeingEarnest = Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/844/pg844.txt"];
ThePictureofDorianGray = Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/174/pg174.txt"];
AnIdealHusband = Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/files/885/885-0.txt"];
LesMiserables = Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/135/pg135.txt"];
NotreDamedeParis = Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2610/pg2610.txt"];
TheManWhoLaughs = Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/12587/pg12587.txt"];

author = Classify[
           <|"William Shakespeare" -> {Othello, Hamlet},
             "Oscar Wilde" -> {TheImportanceOfBeingEarnest, ThePictureofDorianGray},
             "Victor Hugo" -> {LesMiserables, NotreDamedeParis}|>,
           Method -> {"NeuralNetwork"}];
```

Now, by executing `Options[author]`, we get more information about the trained Neural Network:

```
{<|"Common"-><|"Pattern"->_String,"Preprocessors"-><|"Input"->"ToLowerCase" -> "WordTokenize" -> "TokensToTFIDFVector" -> "ReduceDimension","Output"->"IntegerEncodeList"|>,"Decision"-><|"Prior"-><|"Oscar Wilde"->0.3333333333333333`,"Victor Hugo"->0.3333333333333333`,"William Shakespeare"->0.3333333333333333`|>...
```

I'm wondering if there's any way we can see what the preprocessed data is (for example: see what the TFIDF vector or IntegerEncodeList look like).

Comment: Does `FullForm[author]` help?

Comment: That is a great suggestion. FullForm gave me a bit more information. The interesting here is with a Markov classifier, FullForm was able to give me lists of words and values while neural network method gave me a list of hashes (it says type is Murmur3-64) so I'm assuming it's for some sort of lookup array but unfortunately it could not give me the list of words itself. Great suggestion, nevertheless!

Comment: No worries. I'd used `FullForm` a few times out of curiosity to see what was being stored ...but it is not my field so unsure how useful the information is to a "skilled practitioner"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `PrintDefinitions` function may be helpful in understanding the internal working of the processors.

It seems that the internal structure of data is in the form of `MLDataset`, and the processors can be applied directly to the `MLDataset`.

Here is an example:

We first extract the options, which contains the detail of the model

```
opts = First@Options[author];
```

The preprocessor and processor of the input can be obtained by

```
inputPrepro = opts["Input"]["Preprocessor"]
inputPro = opts["Input"]["Processor"]
```

Now we can apply these processors to the inputs, and get an `MLDataset` object

```
processedInput = inputPro@inputPrepro@Keys[data]
(* MachineLearning`MLDataset[<|"f1" -> <|"Type" -> "Text", 
    "Weight" -> 1, 
    "Values" -> {"william shakespeare", "oscar wilde", "victor hugo"},
     "ID" -> 5544833639454981494|>|>, <|"RawExample" -> False, 
  "ExampleNumber" -> 3, "ExampleWeights" -> 1|>] *)
```

Then we can apply the processor in the model to this `MLDataset` object

```
modelPro = First[opts["Models"]]["Processor"];
modelPro@processedInput
(* {{2.71499}, {2.7148}, {2.71468}} *)
```

If you want to look into the individual processor in the modelPro, you can apply the individual processors sequentially

```
{pro1, pro2, pro3, pro4} = modelPro[[2]]["Processors"];

pro4@pro3@pro2@pro1@processedInput
(* {{2.71499}, {2.7148}, {2.71468}} *)
```