# Neural Networks in Predict function

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

I'm trying to reproduce the result giving by a Predict function with a Neural Network as the chosen method.

So, I'm training from this set:

```
trainingset = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 8};
```

and train a simple NN with just one HL with 1 linear neuron:

```
p = Predict[trainingset, Method -> {"NeuralNetwork", "HiddenLayers" -> {{1, "Linear"}}}]
```

By using Options I can have access to the resulting weights from:

```
Normal[Options[p][[1]]][[7]]

"Models" -> {<|"Method" -> "NeuralNetwork", "NeuralNetwork" -> 
<|"NeuronTypes" -> {"Linear", "Linear"}, "CostFunction" -> "SquaredCost", 
 "NumberOfNodes" -> {1, 1, 1}, "L1Regularization" -> 0, "L2Regularization" -> 0.1, 
 "DropOut" -> False, "Weights" -> {{{-0.9752752696739045}}, 
   {{-0.9752752696739043}}}, "Biases" -> {{-5.738324013344273*^-17}, 
   {-1.5516692498423558*^-17}}, "TrainingCostHistory" -> 
  {1.8283207510222368, 0.4788249850114622, 0.04910194009988826, 
   0.042738345120368906, 0.041599875787272395, 0.0410427527972165, 
   0.03861566085385098, 0.03761310711018569, 0.03599253089639499, 
   0.035775402536093924, 0.03573690274038513, 0.03573478075597261, 
   0.035734174870756356, 0.03573417449687247, 0.035734174496067674, 
   0.035734174496065876, 0.03573417449606588, 0.03573417449606589, 
   0.03573417449606589, 0.03573417449606589, 0.03573417449606589, 
   0.03573417449606589}, "TestCostHistory" -> {}|>, "EarlyStopping" -> False, 
"MaxIterations" -> 2250, "FeatureIndices" -> All, "DistributionData" -> 
{NormalDistribution, 0.1785506703441404}, "FeaturePreprocessor" -> 
MachineLearning`PackageScope`Preprocessor["Standardize", {{2.5}, {Sqrt[5/3]}}], 
"ExtractedFeatureNumber" -> 1|>}
```

They are both -0.9752. 
The predict function p gives me as a result:

```
 p[2]=3.73555
```

and now I'm trying to obtain this same result by calculation it by hand. So, since it is a linear NN, and because the biases are nearly zero, we should have.

```
output = (x * w1) * w2 = (2 * -0.9752) * -0.9752 = 1.90203
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you can just shove 2 in there directly?  From your code it looks like features are standardized first. Practically all these options are undocumented too,  I'd be interested in the solution as well.

Comment: Not an answer, but another related question: Where can I find the documentation about predict using ANN? That is, what options are available? How do I specify the number and size of the hidden layers? How to specify the activation functions for the different layers?, etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In version 12, this code does not seem to work anymore. Is there a way to obtain the weights from a NN in version 12?

Answer (score 5):

As @Histograms mentioned in the comment, the features are standardized. Actually, both the input and output are standardized.

In the example, the mean and standard deviation of the input is:

```
input = {1, 2, 3, 4};
μ1 = Mean[input]
σ1 = StandardDeviation[input]
(* 5/2 *)
(* Sqrt[5/3] *)
```

so the linear function that standardized the input is

```
f1 = (# - μ1)/σ1 &
```

while the function that inverts this process is

```
g1 = μ1 + σ1 # &
```

The same for output:

```
output = {2, 3, 6, 8};
μ2 = Mean[output];
σ2 = StandardDeviation[output];  
f2 = (# - μ2)/σ2 &;
g2 = μ2 + σ2 # &;
```

So the prediction can be calculated as:

```
g2[(-0.975275)*(-0.975275)*f1[2]]
(* 3.73555 *)
```

The same as the value from `Predict`. More about processors can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130054/1364).