# How to perform feature selection for machine learning applications?

Tags: functions, fitting, machine-learning

Feature selection is fairly easy in e.g. Python's `scikit-learn` which sports a [module and tutorials](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) or [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/feature-selection.html).
[Mathematica even touts that it uses feature selection](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/highly-automated-machine-learning/) in its automated machine learning algorithms, though I've had trouble finding much more on this, especially anything in Mathematica documentation. Related SE posts are [How to know the internal pre-processing of automatic machine learning function `Classify`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96383/how-to-know-the-internal-pre-processing-of-automatic-machine-learning-function) and [How to view ClassifierFunction's preprocessed data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67159/how-to-view-classifierfunctions-preprocessed-data)

I could probably use Mathematica's [`Variance[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variance.html) or [`Correlation[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Correlation.html) functions for some basic feature selection. I'm also aware that I could try different combinations of features and choose ones with higher accuracy, as described in [How can I determine the importance of variables from Classify?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102762/how-can-i-determine-the-importance-of-variables-from-classify).

Maybe in [`Predict[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Predict.html), there's some option I'm overlooking..

I'm also aware of and a moderate user of the [Wolfram Client Library for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/), in which case I could use some of `scikit-learn`'s functionality, though it would be nice to know if Mathematica has built-in options or if someone has developed some sophisticated code to do this.

Comment: Do FeatureExtract or DimensionReduce have options you're looking for?

Comment: @tad Unfortunately, no, at least from what I can tell. With DimensionReduce, it's mostly PCA-like transforms (PCA, MDS, TSNE, etc.). FeatureExtract is nice with the breadth of feature types (I especially like that it handles Nominal data in Predict for example), but I don't see any options that would indicate which features are most important.

Comment: Wolfram said they might try to work on it. Probably more likely to if others express interest too.

Comment: I would be very interested in this.  I have a high dimensional feature space in the life science space and need to train and test classifiers using a subset of this space.  While I could use DimensionReduction, I'm more interested in what features in the high dimensional space would provide the largest differentiation for my classifier.